# Fetch specific output from stdout_lines and store it in a list

Tags: ansible

I'm working on automating F5 BIG IP configuration decommission.I need to fetch the pool names from the executed arbitrary bigip command. I have stored the content of the output  to a register and wanted to fetch the pool name and store it in a list.

I have achieved till obtaining the wide ip information (which contains Pool name) from the output of the executed command.

Expected output :-

Can i use any Regular expression to fetch the pool information , as far as i know i can do a dot walk to fetch the exact content from JSON . I'm pretty much sure that the output won't be same when there are multiple pool names . What would be the logic if there are multiple pools as well ?

```
---
- name: Playbook to verify the Wideip and fetch the GTM configuration
  hosts: test-gtm.com
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:

    - name: Verify WideIP Exists
      bigip_command:
        user: admin
        password: admin
        commands: "list gtm wideip a wideip"
        validate_certs: no
      register: output
      delegate_to: localhost

    - debug:
        var: output

    - name: Fetch the Pool name from the WideIP
      set_fact:
        gtm_pool: "{{ output.stdout_lines[0][1].split()[0] }}"

``

Output without the dot walk :-

"stdout_lines": [
            [
                "gtm wideip a test.abc.com {", 
                "    pools {", 
                "        test-pool {", 
                "            order 0", 
                "        }", 
                "    }", 
                "}"
            ]


Whole  debug output :-



        "output": {
        "changed": false, 
        "deprecations": [
            {
                "msg": "Param 'server' is deprecated. See the module docs for more information", 
                "version": 2.9
            }, 
            {
                "msg": "Param 'user' is deprecated. See the module docs for more information", 
                "version": 2.9
            }, 
            {
                "msg": "Param 'password' is deprecated. See the module docs for more information", 
                "version": 2.9
            }, 
            {
                "msg": "Param 'validate_certs' is deprecated. See the module docs for more information", 
                "version": 2.9
            }
        ], 
        "executed_commands": [
            "tmsh -c \\\"list gtm wideip a wideip\\\""
        ], 
        "failed": false, 
        "stdout": [
            "gtm wideip a wideip {\n    pools {\n        test-pool {\n            order 0\n        }\n    }\n}"
        ], 
        "stdout_lines": [
            [
                "gtm wideip a wideip {", 
                "    pools {", 
                "        test-pool {", 
                "            order 0", 
                "        }", 
                "    }", 
                "}"
            ]
        ]
    }
}





Debug output consisting of more than single pool:-

ok: [device.abc.com] => {
    "output": {
        "changed": false, 
        "deprecations": [
            {
                "msg": "Param 'server' is deprecated. See the module docs for more information", 
                "version": 2.9
            }, 
            {
                "msg": "Param 'user' is deprecated. See the module docs for more information", 
                "version": 2.9
            }, 
            {
                "msg": "Param 'password' is deprecated. See the module docs for more information", 
                "version": 2.9
            }, 
            {
                "msg": "Param 'validate_certs' is deprecated. See the module docs for more information", 
                "version": 2.9
            }
        ], 
        "executed_commands": [
            "tmsh -c \\\"list gtm wideip a wideip\\\""
        ], 
        "failed": false, 
        "stdout": [
            "gtm wideip a wideip {\n    description wideip\n    pool-lb-mode topology\n    pools {\n        test1-pool {\n            order 1\n        }\n        test2-pool {\n            order 0\n        }\n    }\n}"
        ], 
        "stdout_lines": [
            [
                "gtm wideip a wideip {", 
                "    description wideip", 
                "    pool-lb-mode topology", 
                "    pools {", 
                "        test1-pool {", 
                "            order 1", 
                "        }", 
                "        test2-pool {", 
                "            order 0", 
                "        }", 
                "    }", 
                "}"
            ]
        ]
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Your question is missing major elements. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. More precisely: what is the result of your play (sorry but we cannot guess)? What are you expecting instead  ? What did you try to achieve your goal and what did not work as expected (with details and error messages) ? ...

Comment: @Harsha Nalore Post at least the output of "- debug: var=output" . Please follow: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @VladimirBotka: I have pasted the out put of stdout_lines , Thanks !

Comment: @Harsha Nalore See the answer. Is this what you expect? If not put your expectation into the question.

Comment: The output you show here is not the complete output of that `debug` statement.  Can you show more of the output, including more than a single pool in the result?

Comment: @VladimirBotka: As larsks pointed out the output is not in JSON so we may need to have a different logic. I believe we are close to the solution. I'll be pasting the content of the debug output to the question above.

Comment: @larsks : I have pasted the complete output of the debug statement above  , i'll verify the output bearing more than single pool and update here. Thanks !

Comment: @Harsha Nalore The "different logic" seems to be at the 100+ [F5 modules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/list_of_network_modules.html#f5) level. In particular, you might be better off with the module [bigip_facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/bigip_facts_module.html#bigip-facts-collect-facts-from-f5-big-ip-devices), or [bigip_gtm_pool](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/bigip_gtm_pool_module.html#bigip-gtm-pool-manages-f5-big-ip-gtm-pools) which returns "List of members in the pool".

Comment: @larsks: It works perfectly , thank you  so much ! I was trying to understand the regex you have built to match the line. However i'm not able to figure out , can you comment on how did you arrive at that regex , i was trying to use the regex101 website to build out the expression. I did even try the regex you have built in this URL it says it can't match. Appreciate if you can suggest , thanks !\

Comment: @larsks: Appreciate if you can assist me in understanding the Regex that you have built.Thanks !

Comment: @larsks: thank you so much for taking your time to write a blog about the regular expression used for this scenario , appreciate it !

Comment: @larsks: Where do you test your regex ? Do you use some kindoff tool , because i use regex101.com and it wasn't working as expected.

Comment: I use python to test my python regular expressions.

Comment: @larsks: Thanks  , now while i was trying to pass these pool names to the consecutive playbook i could see it is passing this as "[u\\'test1-pool']" . But i just need "test1-pool" . Any suggestions ?

Comment: @larsks Thank you so very much for all your assistance , you're the master ! It all worked as required.

Comment: @VladimirBotka Thanks for your inputs as well , appreciate it !

Comment: @larsks: Could you assist me with "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56236839/fetch-specific-output-from-registered-output-in-ansible-while-looping-across-mul"

Comment: @larsks : Appreciate if you could assist me on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56236839/fetch-specific-output-from-registered-output-in-ansible-while-looping-across-mul. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parsing that output *robustly* will be tricky, because it is effectively a proprietary serialization format.  If there's a way to get the switch to just give you JSON that would make your life easier (I know some Cisco switches have this option).

To do this The Right Way you would want to write a parser that understood the output format.  But we can cheat, and make lots of assumptions, and solve this with a couple of regular expressions.

I think that in any case we're going to need to parse this output in a tool other than Ansible.  I generally just write a filter module in Python in situations like this, although sometimes "pipe to `awk`" also works.

For parsing this output, I hacked together the following (and dropped it into `filter_plugins/bigip.py` adjacent to my playbook):

```py
import re

# Recall that "\s+" means "one or more whitespace characters"
re_pools = re.compile('''
gtm \s+ wideip \s+ a \s+ (\S+) \s+ { \s+
(?P<parameters>(\S+ \s+ \S+ \s+)*)
pools \s+ { \s+ (?P<pools>
(?:
\S+ \s+ {  \s+
[^}]* \s+
} \s+
)+ \s+
)
}
''', flags=re.VERBOSE)

re_pool = re.compile('''
(\S+) \s+ { \s+ [^}]* \s+ } \s+
''', flags=re.VERBOSE)


def filter_get_pool_names(v):
    combined = ' '.join(v.splitlines())
    res = re_pools.match(combined)

    if not res or not res.group('pools'):
        pools = []
    else:
        pools = re_pool.findall(res.group('pools'))

    return pools


class FilterModule(object):
    filter_map = {
        'get_pool_names': filter_get_pool_names,
    }

    def filters(self):
        return self.filter_map
```

The above defines a `get_pool_names` filter.  If I use it in a playbook like this:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    output:
      stdout: ["gtm wideip a test.abc.com {\n    pools {\n        test-pool1 {\n            order 0\n        }\n        test-pool2 {\n            order 1\n        }\n        test-pool3 {\n            order 2\n        }\n    }\n}"]

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ output.stdout.0 | get_pool_names }}"
```

I get the result:

```
TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "test-pool1", 
        "test-pool2", 
        "test-pool3"
    ]
}
```

Note that I've made assumptions about the format of the output here, and there's really not much in the way of error checking in the filter.  But I think it demonstrates one way of tackling this problem.

**Update**

Regarding:

> while i was trying to pass these pool names to the consecutive playbook i could see it is passing this as "[u\'test1-pool']" . But i just need "test1-pool" . Any suggestions ?

The result of the filter is a list of names. You are trying to treat it as a string. You need to either loop over the result, like this:

```
- set_fact:
    pool_names: "{{ output.stdout.0 | get_pool_names }}"

- debug:
    msg: "processing pool: {{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ pool_names }}"
```

Or refer to individual elements in the list:

```
- debug:
    msg: "the first pool is {{ pool_names.0 }}"
```

Comment: I have added the debug output  in the above question that consist of more than single pool.Please review the same , thanks !

Comment: I've updated the filter to ignore the extraneous information before the `pools` section.

Comment: I was trying to match  using regular expression you have provided but it throws out an error "gtm\s+wideip\s+a\s+(\S+)\s+{..\s+(?P<paramaters> (\S+\s\S+\s+)*)".What does P<paramters> mean ?

Comment: How to ignore the \n "newline" while trying to match using regex ?

Comment: @HarshaNalore, Because this answer didn't seem the right place for it, I've posted an extended discussion of the regular expression [here](http://blog.oddbit.com/post/2019-05-07-unpacking-a-python-regular-exp/). Hope that helps.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a response to your comment.  Perhaps a "+1" is in order at this point.

Answer (score -1):

The content in the question is a series of lines, and it's not even JSON so you can't simply deserialize it. Valid JSON would be

```
{ "gtm wideip a test.abc.com": { "pools": { "test-pool": { "order": 0 }}}}
```

As an example, if such data is available, the play below

```
vars:
  my_stdout_lines:
    gtm wideip a test.abc.com: 
      pools: 
        test-pool: 
          order: 0
        test-pool1: 
          order: 0
        test-pool2: 
          order: 0
tasks:
  - set_fact:
      my_list: "{{ my_stdout_lines|json_query('*.pools.keys(@)') }}"
  - debug:
      var: my_list
```

gives (abridged):

```
"my_list": [
    [
        "test-pool2", 
        "test-pool", 
        "test-pool1"
    ]
]
```

Comment: This isn't a relevant example: the content of your `my_stdout_lines` variable here is a dictionary.  The content in the question is a series of lines, and it's not even JSON so you can't simply deserialize it into a dictionary.